# How to repair NTLDR missing in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, virus, bootloader

My computer running Windows XP was infected with a virus severely. After scanning with Bitdefender Internet Security, my computer restarted and doesn't boot. Black screen appears showing NTDLR is missing:

```
NTLDR is missing
Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart
```

What is the cause behind it? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply copy the NTLDR file (usually located on C:) from another Windows XP *or* Windows Server 2003, and copy it to your computer. Of course, you need to boot using an 'emergency disk', e.g., BartPE.

Or, if you can get your hands on a copy of Hiren's BootCD, there's a tool in there that will restore NTLDR for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Windows XP CD. Boot from it into recovery console ([step 6 in this article](http://voices.yahoo.com/how-fix-ntldr-missing-118259.html)).

Quite often just the commands `fixboot` and `fixmbr` fix the problem, but maybe you will need to copy that `ntldr` file from the CD as well.